# How to pass XSL attribute value into HTML5 data tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, xslt

I am new to XSLT so forgive my noob question.

Here it goes, I am trying to pass the value of a xsl:attribute using javascript.
So when I click on the button it is suppose to get the value of the XSL attribute.
But I could not get the expected output.

The HTML portion of the code is here:

```
<xsl:attribute name="value">
   <xsl:value-of select="110"/>
</xsl:attribute>

<input type="button" name="testBtn" id="testBtn"
   value="Test Button" data-test="$value"/>
```

and the javascript code is here:

```
$("#testBtn").click(function() {
   var outputResult = $(this).attr('data-test');

   console.log(outputResult);
});
```

The expected output when I click on the button:

```
    110
```

I have included a jsfiddle in case my question is unclear
http://jsfiddle.net/rfa75/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot embed XSLT directly in an HTML document. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: XLST is usually used to make a transform with XML and/or HTML. You can generate HTML code based on XML for instance. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the value i need into another form using $.ajax, i'm trying to pass it to another form as a ajax data option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frédéric Hamidi says, you are mixing html with XSL, which is not the way XSLT transformations work.
Anyway, you might need something like this (in your XSL):

```
<input type="button" name="testBtn" id="testBtn" value="Test Button">
  <xsl:attribute name="data-test">
    <xsl:value-of select="110"/><!-- "110" or any expression you should need -->
  </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Which will output this HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="testBtn" id="testBtn" value="Test Button" data-test="110"/>
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks alot, this definitely does what I wanted. Thanks both of you. @X-Pippes too =)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something similar to what you originally had by using an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) (Attribute Value Template (`{}`)).

```
<input type="button" name="testBtn" id="testBtn"
   value="Test Button" data-test="{data-test}"/>
```